# Add fields to Product Type itself

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, products

I want to create product groups and save some data in themselves. but I only could add field to individual product, not product type itself.
Or it is nice if product could have hierarchal structures.

Is there any way to achieve?

Comment: If you simply want to make groups of products I would add a category field to the Product Type you are working with. From there you can give each product one or more categories and then use `relatedTo` queries in templates to pull the products for each group.